# Reading in exotic characters in C++

Tags: c++

I'm working on a program in C++. Part of it reads the columns of a .csv file into vector. Column two contains characters. Most of them are being read correctly, but some (e.g. "Umlaute" like ä, ö, ü or exotic characters like · ) are not being correctly. When they are printed, a stand in character (question mark) appears.

What am I doing wrong?

The program:

```
// Bad but (somewhat) fast encryption. //

#include <iostream>  // For printing to command line (e.g. cout).
#include <fstream>  // For file io.
#include <string>  // Working with strings.
#include <vector>  // For the class "vector".
#include <map>  // For the class "dictianory".


// A function to convert a string to a float.
// TODO: Why is this nececarry and I can't just use stof().
// But stof( "17.40" ) gives just 17.
float stringToFloat(std::string x){
  float result= 0.0;  // Initialize "result" as float and 0,0.
  int len = x.length();  // Extract the length of the passed string.
  int dotPosition = 0;  // Position of the decimal point.

  // Iterate over all characters in the string.
  for (int i = 0; i < len; i++){
    if (x[i] == '.' or x[i] == ','){  // Find the decimal deilimieter.
      dotPosition = len - i  - 1;  // Lock its' position.
    } else {  // Haven't reached decimal point yet.
      result = result * 10.0 + (x[i]-'0');  // Multiply according to position.
    }
  }

  // Handle everything behind the decimal point.
  while (dotPosition--){  // Count the post decimal point digits down.
        result /= 10.0;  // Divide according to position.
  }

  return result;  // Return the produced float.
}


// A new struct containing the three important rows,
struct histogramLine {
  std::string place;
  std::string character;
  std::string abundance;
};


// Function for reading a single line of the histogram file.
std::istream& readLine( std::istream& inputStream, histogramLine& x ){
  getline( inputStream, x.place, '\t');
  getline( inputStream, x.character, '\t');
  getline( inputStream, x.abundance, '\n');
  return inputStream;
} 

// Function for creating a cipher_table.csv.
void newTable( std::string charset, std::string file ){

  std::vector<std::string> places;
  std::vector<char> characters;
  std::vector<float> abundances;
  int lineIndex = 0;

  // Read the file.
  std::ifstream csvRead( charset );

  if ( !csvRead.is_open() ){  // For whatever reason the file wasn't opened.
    std::cout << "File " << charset << " couldn't be opened.";
  } else {  // Otherwise …
    for ( histogramLine line; readLine( csvRead, line ); lineIndex++){
      if( lineIndex > 0 ){
        places.push_back(line.place);
        characters.push_back(line.character[0]);
        abundances.push_back(stringToFloat(line.abundance));
      }
    }
  }

}

// Main function.
int main(int argc, char **argv){  // Must have 2 or 0 arguments. Why?

  std::locale::global( std::locale( "de_DE.utf8" ) );

  /* TODO: Understand, why I need to pass argv[1] to a string instead  of
     using it directly. */
  std::string command = argv[1];  // The command given to the programm.

  if ( command == "table" ){  // Creation of a new cipher table.
    if ( argc > 3 ){  // Enough arguments provided.
      newTable( argv[2], argv[3] );  // Call function for creating a new table.
    } else {
      std::cout << "You must provide a alphabet histogram"
                 << " and a file to output.\n";
    }
  }

  return(0);

}
```

The file beeing read:

```
place   letter  abundance
1.  E   17.40
2.  N   9.78
3.  I   7.55
4.  S   7.27
5.  R   7.00
6.  A   6.51
7.  T   6.15
8.  D   5.08
9.  H   4.76
10. U   4.35
11. L   3.44
12. C   3.06
13. G   3.01
14. M   2.53
15. O   2.51
16. B   1.89
17. W   1.89
18. F   1.66
19. K   1.21
20. Z   1.13
21. P   0.79
22. V   0.67
23. ẞ   0.31
24. J   0.27
25. Y   0.04
26. X   0.03
27. Q   0.02
28. e   17.40
29. n   9.78
30. i   7.55
31. s   7.27
32. r   7.00
33. a   6.51
34. t   6.15
35. d   5.08
36. h   4.76
37. u   4.35
38. l   3.44
39. c   3.06
40. g   3.01
41. m   2.53
42. o   2.51
43. b   1.89
44. w   1.89
45. f   1.66
46. k   1.21
47. z   1.13
48. p   0.79
49. v   0.67
50. ß   0.31
51. j   0.27
52. y   0.04
53. x   0.03
54. q   0.02
55. 1   3
56. 2   14
57. 3   15
58. 4   14
59. 5   20
60. 6   9
61. 7   12
62. 8   3
63. 9   11
64. 0   14
65. !   3
66. "   13
67. §   7
68. $   3
69. %   8
70. &   18
71. /   6
72. (   20
73. )   7
74. =   18
75. ?   10
76. *   3
77. +   7
78. #   7
79. '   9
80. ,   17
81. ;   13
82. .   12
83. -   16
84. _   9
85.     5
86. Ä   6.51
87. Ö   2.51
88. Ü   4.35
89. ä   6.51
90. ö   2.51
91. ü   4.34
92. :   7
93. <   11
94. >   5
95. {   17
96. }   9
97. ^   12
98. ·   13
```

Comment: Using C++ std classes. Without the sarcasm, standard C/C++ have very poor support for utf8 and the notion of string doesn't work well with the idea of variable-length encodings. For example, `char` usually can only represent 8-bit values, so `std::vector<char> characters;` is wrong. You should at elast be doing something like `std::vector<std::string> characters` and never index the utf8 strings.

Comment: `std::stof` works fine: https://ideone.com/5Up9mT. How are you using it?

Comment: Firstly, unless the `stof` problem is really your main problem, this is a long way from the [minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code to help us understand your problem. Secondly, [`stof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof) uses your current C locale for the decimal seperator - it probably it expects `,` for `de_DE`. You can print something, or run in a different locale, to check.

Comment: @bruno Fixed it, thanks.

Comment: @BessieTheCow where are the exotic characters in your link ?

Comment: @bruno OP said in a comment in the code that `stof("17.40")` gives 17.

Comment: Please ask separate questions about stof (if you still want to understand why your numeric locale and string format don't match) and UTF string processing. They're not really related.

Comment: @BessieTheCow the problem concerns "*Umlaute" like ä, ö, ü or exotic characters like ·*" part of the columns 2 (letter) out of the float portion for sure

Comment: @BessieTheCow I compiled the code you posted on ideone.com and it gives 17.4 as expected on my own machine… But not on in the code above. Topic for another day.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Dan M. Declaring the `characters` as a string instead of a vector did the trick. Also I removed the index and just passed the entire string.

I thouht I use char to make it more "memory efficient".